# Issue while aggregating and concatenating two strings in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am facing a hard time performing aggregation and concatenation operations in pyspark.

My requirement is:
I have two float type variables e.g. Price- $41.5, Budget- $32.7. I have to take Price - Budget and round it to two decimal places and then concatenate $ with the new field(convert it to string type.)

I tried creating a udf for the same:

concat_aggregate(x, y) is a function where I took the following steps:

1. z=0
2. x=x.replace("$", ' ')
3. y=y.replace("$", ' ')
4. z=int(x) -int(y)
5. z=round(z,2)
6. z= str(z) + "$"
7. return(z)

I called it with `udf_aggregate() = udf(lambda x, y:concat_aggregate(x, y), StringType())`.

I tried so many things but am getting errors each time. I'd appreciate if you could guide me to the way we can cast, aggregate and concatenate together in pyspark. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be nice if you could add **sample data** and **desired result** to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume this is your dataframe:

```
df.show()
+-----+------+
|Price|Budget|
+-----+------+
|$41.5| $32.7|
|$43.5| $32.7|
|$44.5| $32.7|
+-----+------+
```

First import `functions`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

Then what you can do is to use `regexp_replace` to remove `$` and then `cast` values to float, then `subtract` the values, and put the results in `Difference`:

```
df = df.withColumn('Difference', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Price'), '\$', '').cast('float')- F.regexp_replace(F.col('Budget'), '\$', '').cast('float'))
df.show()

+-----+------+----------+
|Price|Budget|Difference|
+-----+------+----------+
|$41.5| $32.7|  8.799999|
|$43.5| $32.7| 10.799999|
|$44.5| $32.7| 11.799999|
+-----+------+----------+
```

Now it's time to `round` the results, `cast` as string and add $ sign:

```
df = df.withColumn('Result', F.concat(F.lit('$'),(F.round(F.col('difference'),2)).cast('string')))
df.select('Price', 'Budget', 'Result').show()

+-----+------+------+
|Price|Budget|Result|
+-----+------+------+
|$41.5| $32.7|  $8.8|
|$43.5| $32.7| $10.8|
|$44.5| $32.7| $11.8|
+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am glad you helped.